# Can't login to a website using python request package

Tags: python, http, python-requests

The site is http://www.netsimplicity.net/Hult/default.aspx?db=Hult
I've been trying to login to this site using examples given here for python's requests library but without success so far. One of the variations I tried:

```
import requests
import json

username = 'WrongUser'
password = 'WrongPassword'

URL = 'http://www.netsimplicity.net/hult/default.aspx?db=hult'
payload = {
    'Login:txtUsername': username,
    'Login:txtPassword': password,
    'Login:chkRememberMe': 'on',
    'Login:btnLogin': 'Login'
}

session = requests.session()
r = session.get(URL)
r = requests.post(URL, data=json.dumps(payload))
print "request headers"
print r.request.headers
print "request body"
print r.request.body
print "response headers"
print r.headers
print r.status_code
```

I also tried to modify the request headers which didn't help either.

Comment: By giving a quick look at the page, I think it is implementing CSRF. Also, you should use your `session` for the POST request too, not just for the GET.